# Half-Open Interval is Neither Closed nor Open...based on Definition of Topological Space Via Open Sets?

Tags: general-topology

The basic axioms of a topological space in terms of open sets says:

```
A topological space is an ordered pair (X, τ), where X is a set and τ is a 
 collection of subsets of X, satisfying the following axioms:

a) The empty set and X itself belong to τ.

b) Any (finite or infinite) union of members of τ still belongs to τ.

c) The intersection of any finite number of members of τ still belongs to τ.

The elements of τ are called open sets and the collection τ is called a topology 
on X.
```

No problem.

Now...The interval $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

Problem: The simple proof of this shows how the open interval $(0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon)$ does not lie entirely within $[0,1)$. Now this makes sense. But this "lies entirely within" condition is not listed above. So why is it enough to state it as a proof?

Comment: The definition you cited is for a general topological space. The statement that $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed is true in the **usual** topology on $\mathbb R$, where the open sets (i.e., the collection $\tau$) are precisely the sets which can be expressed as unions of open intervals. There are other topologies that can be defined on $\mathbb R$ where the statement that $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed is false.

Comment: So there is no contradiction, just the set must be of the form (a,b) in order to be "open" (in the "usual" topology)?

Comment: In the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, an open set must be of the form $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} (a_{\alpha}, b_{\alpha})$, where $I$ is an arbitrary index set. (In other words, an open set is a union of open intervals.) One can furthermore prove that it's always possible to express an open set in $\mathbb R$ as a **countable disjoint** union of open intervals, but we don't need that fact here.

Comment: So what happens if you then add [0,1) to the topology? What contradiction appears?

Comment: The grammar of "open" takes some getting used to. The fully correct grammar is: "the subset $S$ of the topological space $(X, \tau)$ is open..." meaning that "open" takes three inputs: a set $X$, a topology $\tau$ on $X$, and a subset $S$ of $X$. People often leave out $\tau$ if it is understood from context, and novices often leave out $X$ because they don't understand the grammar. So, the correct statement is: $[0, 1)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology generated by open intervals.

Comment: @Alexander: no contradiction appears. You're just talking about a different topology now.

Comment: Well, you can't add **only** that set, because then the result will no longer be a topology. For example, it won't be closed under complements because the complement of $[0,1)$ won't be included. And it won't be closed under unions or finite intersections either. However, one can consider the topology **generated** by the usual open sets along with $[0,1)$. This is by definition the intersection of all topologies containing the usual open sets and $[0,1)$, or equivalently, the smallest topology containing all of these sets.

Comment: Why won't it be closed under unions or finite intersections? I guess this is my original question.

Comment: Because it won't include for example $[0,1) \cup (2,3)$ or $[0,1) \cap (-1/2, 1/2) = [0, 1/2)$. If you add one new set to an existing topology, you have to also add all sets that can be formed by unions and finite intersections that include the new set.

Comment: Ok nice. I will try to write an answer.

Comment: Oops, ignore "closed under complements" in my previous comment. A topology is **not** required to be closed under complements. (The complement of an open set is closed, not necessarily open.) I was probably thinking of sigma-algebras. But the rest of what I wrote is correct: a topology is required to be closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another (equivalent) definition for a topology : in terms of neighborhoods (see e.g. Bourbaki General Topology Ch I). For the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, the neighborhoods of $x_0$ are precisely the sets which contain some $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ and the open sets are precisely those sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
(\forall x_0\in U)(\exists \epsilon>0)((x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)\subset U)
$$
the last inclusion gives a meaning to *lies entirely*. So, there is no contradiction.

Comment: I think it is important for books to make it clear that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: You're right. I learned it in Bourbaki and you can find this in Bourbaki General Topology Ch I § 1 (p17 and seq.). They got from open set ---> neighbourhoods (their spelling is such) and then in reverse direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you add $[0,1)$ to the set of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. to the "usual" topology), then further sets must be added to the topology in order to maintain consistency with the OP's axioms. Consider taking $[0,1) \cap (-1/2,1/2) = [0,1/2)$. This is neither open nor closed, *despite being a subset of $\mathbb{R}$*.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning the lower limit topology here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology which does indeed include all those further sets, but isn't the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.